# In Oracle how do you read a Count(*) from a table into a variable?

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle how do you read a `Count(*)` from a table into a variable?

In Microsoft SQL Server, you would do like

```
select @variable = count(*) from Table where x=1;
```

I tried similarly in Oracle to no avail:

```
SELECT v_count_of_rows_bad := Count(*) FROM SCHEMANAME.TABLENAME WHERE ...;
```

Comment: [PL/SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL#PL.2FSQL_Anonymous_Block) is all needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use a `SELECT INTO`

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO v_count_of_rows_bad
  FROM schemaname.tablename
 WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy Peasie:

```
DECLARE
  v_count_of_rows_bad NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count_of_rows_bad FROM SCHEMANAME.TABLENAME WHERE ...;
END
```